# Where does "tables" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

> The profusion of food showed itself at dinner, where, if the tables did not groan, the guests surely did: for each person is expected to eat of every dish.
>
> - The Origin of Species by Charles Darwin

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *Table* meets the conventional dictionary definition, [a piece of furniture](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/table_1) consisting of a flat surface held above the floor. Please [edit] your post to explain further if this is insufficient. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: Thank you choster!

Answer (score 1):

It means what it normally means:

> a piece of furniture with a flat top and one or more legs, providing a level surface on which objects may be placed, and that can be used for such purposes as eating, writing, working, or playing games.

There is some anthropomorphism in talking about them "groaning". The imagery is comparing a person whose is holding up so much that they are struggling and groaning, to tables being close to the most they can hold up (and possibly bending under the strain, and making a noise doing so).

Comment: 'Groaning table' is a stock expression - see https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/groan (definition Verb 5).

Comment: And thus, as @KateBunting says, Darwin is making a pun: the groaning tables practically groan themselves.

Comment: Thank you to you all!